# How to convert Radiant code back to R

Tags: r, graphics, shiny, analytics, radiant

radiant is a great tool for business analytics. I made great analysis using it and generated the code. My question is, how to bring back the R code generated on Radiant back to my Markdown on Rstudio so my R script can become self contained?

So far, I tried library(radiant) then when I apply the commands for instance Visualise(dataset, blabla) it simply does't work. I am wondering is there anyone with the same problema. I have read all the documentation and it does not say much about it! Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
library(radiant)
visualize(mtcars, xvar = "cyl", yvar = "mpg", type = "scatter")
```

Also, if you set the first dropdown in *R > Report* to `To Rmd` code will be sent to an open Rmarkdown file in Rstudio. You will still need to load the data explicitly in the Rmarkdown file as well.

[image]